# Find Which Nth Child A Div is Within Another Div

Tags: javascript

Finding the solution to this will yield a solution to a higher level problem that I have

```
<div>
  <div class='childDiv'></div>
  <div class='childDiv'></div>
  <div class='childDiv'></div>
</div>

var childrenDivs = document.querySelectorAll('childDiv');

childrenDivs.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log('This is child number: ' + [insert code]);
});
```

I want it to output

```
This is child number: 1
This is child number: 2
This is child number: 3
```

I can't figure out how to find the child position of `value`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
childrenDivs.forEach(function(value, i) {
  console.log('This is child number: ' + (i + 1));
});
```

Higher-order functions like `forEach()`, generally return the iterator (aka the index of current value in the array) as the second and optional parameter.

Since arrays are indexed starting from 0, but we want to start from 1, we need to add always 1 to the iterator before logging it into the console.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to put a `.` before `childDiv` in `childrenDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.childDiv');`

```
<div>
    <div class='childDiv'></div>
    <div class='childDiv'></div>
    <div class='childDiv'></div>
</div>
<script>
    var childrenDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.childDiv');
    console.log(childrenDivs);
    childrenDivs.forEach(function(currentValue, index) {
        console.log('This is child number: ' + index + 1);
    });
</script>
```

and you should add the `index` argument to your function.

forEach also can have the third argument too. but the second and the third are optional.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp